# Evaluate a double integral bounded by two circles

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral $\iint_R y \ dR$ where $D$ is a region between the circles $x^2+y^2=2x$ and $x^2+y^2=4$ and on the first quadrant.

Is my answer true?

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{2\cos\theta}^2r^2sin\theta \ drd\theta$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you at least drawn the region $D$?  Can such a drawing help guide you to the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to check your answer is to solve the problem in a different way.  Try isolating $y$ in the two equations and setting this up as a double integral $dy dx$.  Then evaluate both the $dr d \theta$ integral and the $dy dx$ integral; I do believe that your two answers will be equal, which is a pretty good indication that your polar integral setup is correct.